# How to unblock a blocked toilet?

Tags: toilet, blockage

I have a toilet which drains out quite slowly and water rises to the brim when the flush is exercised.

I have already used the plunger multiple times to try to see if it makes a difference, but it has not helped much. The water level still takes about 30 minutes to go low after a flush. I am clueless at this point.

Is there anything else I can try? Is there a 'draino' equivalent for toilets?

Comment: Did this happen suddenly?  Or has it gotten worse over time?  Are you in a house or a condo? Are you a renter or an owner?

Comment: Yes the slowing down happened suddenly. Or atleast as far as I remember. We are in a condo and a renter. But I don't want to bother the owner for this.

Comment: Should a product like this http://www.homedepot.com/p/ZEP-64-oz-Septic-System-and-Cesspool-Treatment-ZLST648/100010585 be ok to use?

Comment: Toilet snake'll work if you can get someone to confess to dropping a toothbrush or its like down there. Such objects can be remarkably resustant to plunging.

Comment: If you are a renter, then I *would* bother the owner.  That is part of what you get when you pay rent:  they take care of maintenance issues for you.  You shouldn't be paying more money and spending time to fix your own maintenance issues.  You're already paying for it in your rent.

Comment: @Nick2253 Yes, except the owner is 87 years old. And we have an agreement that I only bother him for the major stuff (roof caves in, refrigerator breaks down) in return for a slightly lower rent.

Comment: @Nick2253 It might depends on the country/region but where I live (Belgium) the tenant usually have to take care of this kind of maintenance issues, not the owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a toilet snake as @Wayfaring Stranger suggested. The home depot treatment you looked at is not a drain cleaner but a septic treatment. You might try warm water. When the water is low in the bowl (as in after plunging), slowly add a large pot of warm water to the bowl. Use warm water from the faucet not boiling water. Boiling water may crack the porcelain. Let it sit for about 5 minutes. Plunge it again. then flush. The warm water may soften soap or grease that is in the trap.

Answer (score 2):

Try substituting your plunger for a more powerful [bellows plunger](https://www.google.com/search?q=bellows%20plunger).

[image]